# What are the most popular recruiters' filters when they decide (not) to contact the candidate back?

Tags: resume, recruitment, europe

What are the most popular recruiters' filters when they decide (not) to contact the candidate back?

This is a question I'd like to ask here, in order to receive answers based on facts and your experience. However, I don't want to know it just for knowing it. Now I'm going to explain my certain doubt.

I'm a data analyst and jobs I'd be interested in require generally the following basic technologies (at least two): SQL, Excel, R or Python, Tableau or equivalents.

Now, my biggest strengths when it comes to technologies in general are in fact R and SQL. It is certain that I'm going to list them at the top in my CV. However, my Excel is not that strong. What is more, I've got to know Python and Tableau only superficially, on basic level.

On the other hand, I've got other skills which are not directly related to my (future) job: Java and C++ (both more or less on my Excel's level) and, most interestingly, I know a whole bunch of (human) languages. These skills are hardly ever mentioned in any job advertisement.

The point of my post: I don't know if the probability that a recruiter contacts me back is higher if a) or b), where:

- a) my Excel, Python and Tableau skills are more visible in my CV,
- b) my (human) languages, Java and C++ are more visible in my CV.

It's a common idea that the more things you can do, the more valuable you are, then there's an Italian saying "impara l'arte e mettila da parte", but I'm not sure if recruiters are more interesting in my epic singing and swimming skills or my basic Python skills.

I live in EU.

Comment: The filters will vary across different companies and different recruiters, thus we can't guess which those are and I fear this makes your question off-topic. Consider reading the [help/dont-ask] to see which things are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the specifics are going to change by time and place and get too narrow for a good Workplace Question.

That said - my experience has been that many recruiting entities (both internal and external) - will parse based on hitwords anywhere within the data you provide.  It's not a human reading the CV, so top of CV vs. bottom of CV doesn't matter - the robot will find it regardless.

It may be worth a pass through SEO writing (Search Engine Optimization) or sites that give tips for specific platforms like Linked In or Monster - as the art of doing this can vary from platform to platform.

Past that - the document that you submit should be written with the humans in mind.  A good way to help them is to both give a skills section and then mention how/when the skill was used in a project or job.  For example:

---

Experience:

Languages:  C, C++, Java, Python
...

Work History:

- Job A, Title, years

Completed the full lifecycle of a project to do X using primarily Java with specialized drivers written in C.  Project did ...., specific contribution was...

- Personal project

Currently developing open source code in Python to do Z, project can be found (site), currently used to host functionality for...

---

That gives the reader a double hit - showing them not only the skill but how you used it.  Don't do over kill here - no one really wants to read a paragraph of work history that every bit of tech you ever worked on.  It's a thing to do for stuff that is a seriously big deal for the impact to the project and your skill set.

From there, what what skills to put where is also a factor of what is most marketable for the job you want in the place you want it - I would suggest local networking groups and mentors are a good source for this.  But also skimming job opportunities and looking for patterns.

Comment: Yes, IME the project list with used technologies has been useful, as has been including really obscure technologies you have a bit of experience with. Recruiters don't know if a "serial port" is something cutting-edge, but if it's in the list of requirements, the candidates who mention having used one go to the top. Don't overdo it though, the sorting is usually a manual process, where they look at the context of where they found the keywords, and that needs to be readable and not stink of SEO.